# View init.d script used by Spring-boot

Tags: spring-boot

I've generated a [fully executable](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/deployment-install.html) spring-boot jar

Is it possible to view or generate the script that the init.d service uses for the jar?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The script is added to the start of the jar. You can see it using `less`, for example:

```
$ less target/your-app-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
```